# Contaminating feature in case statement taking long time run complete query

Tags: sql-server, join

Contaminating feature in case statement taking long time run complete query.Below is my query.Any suggestions?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.IndexID,
       a.IndexShortName,
       a.IndexCode,
       a.SourceCode,
       b.sourcecode,
       CASE
           WHEN a.IndexID = b.IndexID
                AND a.sourcecode = b.sourcecode
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.[ModifiedDatetime], 101) = '11/14/2017'
           THEN 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
       END AS IndexDM_Load,
       CASE
           WHEN a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.indexID)
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.[ModifiedDatetime], 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.indexID)
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.[ModifiedDatetime], 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = e.RIMESSource + e.RIMESIndexSymbol
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.FileLoadTime, 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = f.Source + f.Symbol
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.FileLoadTime, 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), g.indexID)
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), g.FileLoadTime, 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), h.indexID)
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), h.FileLoadTime, 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), k.indexID)
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), k.FileLoadTime, 101) = '11/14/2017'
                AND a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), l.indexID)
                AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), l.FileLoadTime, 101) = '11/14/2017'
           THEN 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
       END AS Staging_Load
FROM [IndexDM].[dbo].[IndexReference] a
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].[dbo].[IndexReturn] b ON a.IndexID = b.IndexID
                                                  AND a.sourcecode = b.sourcecode
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.MSCIDailyReturn c ON a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.indexID)
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.MSCIIndexReference d ON a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.indexID)
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.RIMESIndexConstituents e ON a.SourceIndexID = e.RIMESSource + e.RIMESIndexSymbol
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.RIMESIndexValues f ON a.SourceIndexID = f.Source + f.Symbol
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.RussellGlobalDailyConstituents_Dev_Top_200 g ON a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), g.indexID)
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.RussellGlobalDailyConstituents_Dev_Top_200CAD h ON a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), h.indexID)
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.RussellGlobalDailyHoldings k ON a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), k.indexID)
     LEFT JOIN [IndexDM].staging.RussellUSIndexReturns l ON a.SourceIndexID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), l.indexID);
```

Comment: Why are you repeating your join conditions in your case expression? And why do you convert a date to varchar if you only need to check against another date? If you compare to a date literal a convertion is not necessary. Otherwise, there is nothing obvious concerning performance. Did you check the execution plan, are indices available? Note if you use a function on an attribute (like convert) any index on that attribute cannot be used.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is not in the CASE statement. However you can re-write it like that: CASE WHEN '11/14/2017' IN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.[ModifiedDatetime], 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.[ModifiedDatetime], 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.FileLoadTime, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.FileLoadTime, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), g.FileLoadTime, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), h.FileLoadTime, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), k.FileLoadTime, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), l.FileLoadTime, 101)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Staging_Load

Comment: Why are you repeating your join conditions in your case expression? -I need to compare those two columns.so i am repeating join condition in case statement also.

Comment: Is there any  way to simplify this code?It would be great if you can modify code for me

Comment: why do you convert a date to varchar if you only need to check against another date?--I need to compare date with ModifiedDatetime.MY SSRS report having date like this(111/14/2017).so i am converting date to varchar.